# Html5 Server Events library for AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm wondering if there is any angular library to deal with server events. Currently, i'm using:

```
                var source = new EventSource('/api/stream');

                source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.time = JSON.parse(e.data);
                    });
                }, false);

                source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
                    // Connection was opened.
                }, false);

                source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
                    if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
                        // Connection was closed.
                    }
                }, false);
```

So, is there any already existing library to manage it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a server event lib for angular, but there is a websocket lib for angular https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io. Socket.io uses WebSocket, and WebSocket is a more popluar solution for streaming events from server.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking not to use WebSocket, really need to use html5 server events.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpfull for you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFxPFgGaEqk